# Godot addressing/ accessing instanced objects

Tags: object, instance, game-development, godot

I am making a 2D platformer game in Godot,
I create an object using the code:

```
if currentPlayers < playerLimit:
    var person = humanScene.instance()
    add_child(person)
    person.position = Vector2(90, 300)
    currentPlayers += 1
    print(person.position)
```

This works well, but in the "_physics_process(delta):" function, if i try doing:

```
    "print(person.position)"
```

it says:

"Invalid get index 'position' (on base: 'null instance')"

No matter what I try, my code can't seem to find the instanced object to find its position (i need its position every frame).
Is there a special way to access instanced objects data (such as their positions?) thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue of [scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)). The variable `person` is defined only within the `if`, and is not available in `_physics_process`.

You'll want to first define the variable outside the limited scope, and then set its value inside the `if`. For example:

```
var person = null


func some_function_where_this_happens():
    if currentPlayers < playerLimit:
        person = humanScene.instance()
        add_child(person)
        person.position = Vector2(90, 300)
        currentPlayers += 1
        print(person.position)


func _physics_process(delta):
    print(person.position)
```

As it looks like your intention is to support multiple players, you'll probably want to switch the `var person = null` part for an array that holds all the players.